# Active Record- How to select a column with relationship?

Tags: yii

Projects can have unlimited number of columns (to form a table or something), relationship MANY to MANY. To implement this `tbl_project_rel_column` is created. It `stores project_id`, `column_id` AND pos **position** of column in Project table.

I am using AC database approach. I have 2 models Project and Column.

Project model's relations method:

```
public function relations(){
   return array(
...
'columns'=>array(self::MANY_MANY,'Column','tbl_project_rel_column('p_id','c_id')
);
}
```

Now can get all project's columns using something like this:

```
$model = Project::model()->findbyPk($p_id);
$columns = $model->columns;
```

But column doesn't store 'pos'(position) value of it's certain project.

How to get 'pos' value of tpl_project_rel_column table of certain project and certain column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`through`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through) feature instead of `MANY_MANY`. It may also be useful to [index](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-options) the results by the `position` column. Try something like this:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'projectColumns' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProjectRelColumn', 'p_id', 'index'=>'position'),
        'columns' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Column', 'c_id', 'through'=>'projectColumns'),
}
```

Now you can query for projects with columns like this:

```
$projects = Project::model()->with('columns')->findAll();
foreach($projects as $project) {
    // projectColumns are indexed by position. You can sort by this now:
    ksort($project->projectColumns)
    foreach($project->projectColumns as $pos => $projectColumn)
        echo "Pos: $pos Column: {$projectColumn->column->name}";
}
```